# I want to run and kill a process with same batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have bitlord I want this program to run when i click a batch file and when i don't want this program to run i want to kill it with same batch file. Can anyone please write the script Thanks a lot for giving your time.
I tried it scripting but failed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You will get better responses if you provide more detail and specifics about what you tried and how it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If bitlord is not running then this will launch it
If bitlord is     running then this will kill it

Change line 2 and line 3 to set the `program name` and `path`.

```
@echo off
set "program=bitlord.exe"
set "folder=c:\program files\bitlord"
tasklist |find /i "%program%" >nul || start "" "%folder%\%program%" & goto :EOF
tasklist |find /i "%program%" >nul && taskkill /f /im "%program%" & goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks @joedf - just to clarify that they are conditional operators in Windows rather than `or` & `and`.  Here `||` runs on errorlevel 1 and `&&` runs on errorlevel 0

Comment: hmmm, yes you are right ;) as described here: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: @echo off
:search
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq bitlord.exe" | find /i "bitlord.exe" 
IF %ERRORLEVEL% ==0 GOTO kill
IF %ERRORLEVEL% ==1 GOTO run
goto end
:kill
taskkill /f /im bitlord.exe
goto end
:run
start "" /b F:\Bitlord\bitlord.exe
exit

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I think i understand your question now:

```
@echo off
taskkill.exe /f /im notepad.exe
start calc.exe
```

The magic is to use the start command which starts a new command asynchronous. Meaning, it doesn't wait for the termination.

Comment: and how can i run and kill it with same abc.bat file
there has to something like "loop" "if"...

Comment: ah you mean, you have abc.cmd which might run and if you start abc.cmd again, you want to terminate all instances of it?

Comment: NO i want to use abc.bat to run(whenever it like to open program) and kill(when i dont want ie..kill it) my program.....

SO i want to do these two actions with single batch file....